# $|n^\alpha \sin n| \to \infty$ for some $\alpha$?

Tags: limits

Does there exist $\alpha>0$ such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} |n^\alpha \sin n| = \infty$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: It is considered good practice to say what you have tried doing so far, and this will let people help you and give relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

$|n^\alpha sinn|=n^\alpha |sinn|$. Since $lim|sinn|$ has many closure points, (the set of closure points is the segment [0,1]), the sequence $|n^\alpha sinn|$ diverges too. But it does not tend to infinity! It has many closure points. So there is no such $\alpha$ to fill in that equation.

Comment: The question states: Does there exist $\alpha >0$.

Comment: Oops, you're right...hehe. Anyway, in the first line I think you mean that the sequence $\;\{\sin n\}\;$ has many closure points. This though must be proven, and perhaps the OP's doubt is this.